# Select tag not display default option in angular8

Tags: angular, typescript

if I simply use  and  like this:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <form>
    <select
      type="checkbox"
      name="vehicle1"
      (change)="onchange()"
    >
      <option>
        1
      </option>
      <option>
        2
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

it goes well , the select will default chose the first option. but if I do this:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <form>
    <select
      type="checkbox"
      name="vehicle1"
      [(ngModel)]="selectValue"
      (change)="onchange()"
    >
      <option [ngValue]="1">
        1
      </option>
      <option [ngValue]="2">
        2
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  public selectValue = "1";

  constructor() {}

  onchange() {
    console.log("onchange");
    console.log(this.selectValue);
  }
}
```

add ngmodel and ngValue , and the select tag will display empty by default.

I know there is a way to add this line to display a dropdown title:

 `<option [ngValue]="'none'" disabled>Select SortType</option>`

but I don't want , I expect it display the first option by default.
is there any way to achive that?

[this is my sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/angularplayground-x380r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `[ngValue]` you are putting it as `number` not a type of `string`

Either change it to `[ngValue]="'1'"` or change `public selectValue = 1;`

Comment: it works! thank you , but in my real project . I bind a object to ngValue, I display it like `object.value` and I need to use object.id to do something else. so in this scene , ngValue is an object , but when I set the `public selectValue = 1;` it still works. and default choose the first option. do you know why?

Comment: Can you provide an example on that codesandbox? I wasn't able to replicate that, in order to do what you said, you need to use `[compareWith]` if your ngValue is an object.